# Cannot send jQuery Ajax HTTP Request inside chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to send a jQuery Ajax HTTP Request inside google chrome extensions. I have the jQuery library imported, and I used the following code:

```
    $.ajax({
            method: "PUT",
            url: "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/"+id+"/od6/private/full/"+cell,
            headers: {'If-Match': '*'},
            contentType: 'application/atom+xml',
            data: data
        }).done(function(msg) {
            alert("Data Saved: "+JSON.stringify(msg));
        }).fail(function(e){
            alert("There was a problem!\n"+JSON.stringify(e));
        })
```

But whenever I try, it shows me a message says:

```
    There was a problem!
    {"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error"}
```

But I don't get this message when I run the same HTML page(which has imported this javascript code) out side the extension(as a single html page), I success every time.

Why would this happen? How do I send this request inside my extension?

Note: The reason I don't use XMLHttpRequest() is because I have to send headers and datas(which is the `<entry>...</entry>` tag that is required by google sheets api)alone with the request. I don't know how to do that in XMLHttpRequest(). If XMLHttpRequest() DOES WORK, please give me a code example using XMLHttpRequest() to send headers and datas.

Comment: Is that in a content script or a background page?  Popup?

Comment: What is your manifest file?

Comment: No, there is a button on the popup window. Once user has clicked this button, a new HTML page(which I have packed with the extension) popup in a new tab. @ImanK

Comment: View my entire manifest.son file at this link https://docs.google.com/document/d/1z7vqpt15yFKyAAKjvKTVM_juDGzUNmSWtf_esfezk6E/edit?usp=sharing @epascarello

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your mainifest file try changing

```
"permissions": [
    "storage",
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/"
  ]
```

to

```
"permissions": [
    "storage",
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/",
    "https://*.google.com/"
  ]
```